# How to issue and consume JWT using ServiceStack's JwtAuthProvider

Tags: c#, servicestack, jwt

Looking at the [JwtAuthProvider documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JWT-AuthProvider) for ServiceStack, it seems that a lot of JWT functionality is given out-of-the-box. However I really need to look at some working example. I could not find any in the example directory for ServiceStack.

What I'd like to see, is an example code that shows:

1. How to issue a token with some claims.
2. How to decode the token and inspect the claims.

Just using some "Hello world" service. Does anyone have some code that shows this or know where to look?

Ideally, the signing would use RSA, but right now this is not that important...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The JWT AuthProvider is what Issues the JWT token which it populates based on the User Session. You can add your own metadata in the tokens and inspect it with the [CreatePayloadFilter and PopulateSessionFilter](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload).

[JWT is enabled](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks/blob/d87fa2a2b364831cfbd00786b6ed8b716137226e/src/TechStacks/TechStacks/js/user/services.js#L30) in both the AngularJS http://techstacks.io Example by just making a call to `/session-to-token` after the user successfully authenticates with their OAuth Provider, e.g:

```
$http.post("/session-to-token");
```

This converts their currently authenticated session into a JWT Token which it uses for future subsequent requests.

Likewise JWT is also used in http://gistlyn.com which uses a [Customized JwtAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Gistlyn/blob/83a79281aafb923a0835bf9c17c36e5a8417c5ea/src/Gistlyn.ServiceInterface/AppData.cs#L130) to embed the Github OAuth Access Token Secret into the JWT Token then uses the `PopulateSessionFilter` to extract it from the JWT Token and populate it back in the Users Session:

```
appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
new IAuthProvider[] {
    new GithubAuthProvider(appHost.AppSettings),
    //Use JWT so sessions survive across AppDomain restarts, redeployments, etc
    new JwtAuthProvider(appHost.AppSettings) 
    {
        CreatePayloadFilter = (payload, session) =>
        {
            var githubAuth = session.ProviderOAuthAccess.Safe()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Provider == "github");
            payload["ats"] = githubAuth != null 
                ? githubAuth.AccessTokenSecret : null;
        },

        PopulateSessionFilter = (session, obj, req) => 
        {
            session.ProviderOAuthAccess = new List<IAuthTokens>
            {
                new AuthTokens { Provider = "github", AccessTokenSecret = obj["ats"] }
            };
        } 
    },
}));
```

Gistlyn uses a similar approach to TechStacks to using JWT Tokens [by calling /session-to-token](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Gistlyn/blob/83a79281aafb923a0835bf9c17c36e5a8417c5ea/src/Gistlyn/src/app.tsx#L69) after the User has authenticated with Github OAuth using [JavaScript's new fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch("/session-to-token", { method:"POST", credentials:"include" });
```

#### [JWT Stateless Auth Tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/RazorRockstars.Console.Files/StatelessAuthTests.cs)

For other examples you can look at [JWT RSA Tests which uses CreateJwtPayload](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8baeb15350a17248fb3d3155a747a490af648735/tests/RazorRockstars.Console.Files/StatelessAuthTests.cs#L371) which shows examples of manually creating JWT Tokens in code.

Comment: Excellent, just to make sure - I will have to manually create a route and method for delivering the jwt right? And also validate using a RequestFilterAttribute for example? Do you have some example that shows how to validate the authHeader?

Comment: @Werner The JWT AuthProvider itself provides [several ways of retrieving the JWT Token](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JWT-AuthProvider#retrieve-token-with-api-key)

Comment: mythz, again in awe and saved by your code. thank you.